# What is the difference between the user in the _Unsubscribe data view and the users in the _Subscribers data view with a status of 'unsubscribed'?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm getting a different number when running a query to give me the number of subscribers in the _Unsubscribe data view and the numbers of users in the _Subscribers data view with status of 'unsubscribed'.

Any idea why?

Also- which data view truly reflects global unsubscription?

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking at the underlying SQL right now, and I can tell you at least 2 differences.

1) The unsubscribe view is joining the Unsubscribe stats table (the actual event) against the subscribers, and is only returning 6 months of data.  In the subscriber view you may have subscribers unsubscribed for much longer.

2) The subscribers view filters out deleted subscribers.

In summary, the unsubscribe view is primarily about the unsubscribe event, the subscribers views is about... subscribers!  (There are a couple more differences that would require more homework, but hopefully this helps for now).

Comment: Thanks much! When taking a snapshot of the sytem - which of the two data view truly reflects the number of unsubscirbes in the system?

Comment: You will likely care about the subscribers view more, because it will tell you the current state of the subscriber regardless of when they unsubscribed.

Comment: I believe _Unsubscribe also includes list unsubs as well, which would not be reflected in _Subscribers status.